# How to make a debian script run on startup?

Tags: debian, startup, init, boot

I am running Debian 6.0 and I am trying to get a very simple init script to work during boot.

I am running the following commands:

$ cd /etc/init.d

$ pico script

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          script
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by script.
### END INIT INFO

# PATH should only include /usr/* if it runs after the mountnfs.sh script
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
DESC="script..."
NAME=script
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/$NAME
DAEMON_ARGS="--options args"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME

# Some things that run always
echo "Welcome!!!!!" | tee /$HOME/hello.txt

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting script blah "
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping script blah"
    echo "Could do more here"
    ;;
reload)
    echo "reload"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/blah {start|stop}"
   exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

$ chmod 755 script

$ chown root:root script

$ insserv script

It **does** work with ./script start. But it does not at startup.

**I'm using *insserv* instead of *update-rc.d* because I'm getting this error:

*"update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing"*

What am I missing? =(

Comment: `update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing` is an info msg. You should see links to your script in /etc/rc[2-5S].d . To test it, use `service script start`

Comment: Hi Fabien R, thanks for your reply. Effectively my script appears in those directories, however when testing it I'm getting 
*S18script: unrecognized service*

Comment: What does `type script` return ?